# Button android, text position

Tags: java, android, android-button

I create some buttons in my java code. The probleme is the text that i create for this button is always center, do you know how to change is position. I've search and no found because i create it in the java code, not in the xml

```
 Button moncasier = new Button (this);
  moncasier.setText("casier numéro :"+i);
  moncasier.setTextSize(30);

  moncasier.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_casier));
  layoutDesCasiers = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.affichecasier);
  layoutDesCasiers.addView(moncasier);
```

Thanks for the time you spend to me and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
moncasier.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

you can use [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29) for text alignment, Bottom is an example above.

Comment: Thanks you very much, i'll put it " accepted " in 5 minutes (: